# Knex.js Select Average and Round

Tags: mysql, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am switching an application from PHP/MYSQL to Express and am using knex to connect to the MYSQL database.  In one of my queries I use a statement like such (I have shortened it for brevity.)

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(Q1),2) AS Q1 FROM reviews WHERE id=? AND active='1'
```

I am able to use ROUND if I use knex.raw but I am wondering if there is a way to write this using query builder.  Using query builder makes dealing with the output on the view side so much easier than trying to navigate the objects returned from the raw query.

Here is what I have so far in knex.

```
let id = req.params.id;

knex('reviews')
//Can you wrap a ROUND around the average?  Or do a Round at all? 
.avg('Q1 as Q1')
.where('id', '=', id)
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `raw` inside `select`. In this case:

```
knex('reviews')
  .select(knex.raw('ROUND(AVG(Q1),2) AS Q1'))
```

Check the docs [here](http://knexjs.org/#Raw) for more examples and good practices when dealing with raw statements.

Comment: Hi Daniel,  thank you for the response.  This does work for me but I guess I was wondering if knex can do rounding as a "method" I guess.  Like knex('reviews').round('Q1 as Q1').where('id', '=', id) without having to use raw.  My current setup is knex.raw(sqlquery, [id]) and I feed in a sql query from a variable.

Comment: AFAIK, knex does not have a round method or anything similar. The problem with using `knex.raw` by itself is it requires you to parse the returned object. The above snippet bypasses that issue.

Comment: Agreed on the parsing part, it saved a huge amount of returned information to have to sort through!  Thank you!